# Restrict File Type to Multiple File Uploader

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload, image-uploading

I would like some help in allowing only JPG, PNG, PDF, and DOCX files to be uploaded with the solution found at this [**JSFIDDLE Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UXEngineer/w27zk4vy/)

The javascript that performs the file uploading is as follows:

```
function makeFileList() {
    var input = 
document.getElementById("filesToUpload");
    var ul = 
document.getElementById("fileList");
    while (ul.hasChildNodes()) {
      ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      li.innerHTML = input.files[i].name;
      ul.appendChild(li);
    }
    if (!ul.hasChildNodes()) {
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      li.innerHTML = 'No Files Selected';
      ul.appendChild(li);
    }
  }
```

I do not need a warning to be displayed if a user attempts uploaded a file type that is not whitelisted.  So the outcome is to only show the allowed files on the screen.

Thank for your any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the **accept=".jpg,.png,.pdf,.docx"** in input.

```
<input type="file" name="filesToUpload" id="filesToUpload" multiple="" accept=".jpg,.png,.pdf,.docx" onchange="makeFileList();">
</div>
```